# SQL Request with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I have two tables `order` and `retailer`.

In the order the address is an integer value and represent the id of the retailer.

I need to select the address from the retailer table.

I believe I have to do something like:

```
Select * from order where (select .....)
```

I cannot seem to get my syntax right.

EDIT

here is my tables script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `commande` (
  `CO_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CO_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `CO_Facturation_Adresse` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CO_Livraison_Adresse` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CO_Statut` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CO_Detaillant` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CO_Tag` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CO_Number_Commande` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CO_Amount_Untaxed` float(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CO_Amount_Tax` float(10,0) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2870 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and here is my retailer table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detaillant` (
  `DE_No` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `DE_Nom` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DE_DescFR` text,
  `DE_DescEN` text,
  `DE_Site` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE_Actif` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DE_NoTel` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE_Adresse` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE_FkProvince` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE_Ville` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE_CodePostal` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE_NoTelSansFrais` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE_LunDeb` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `DE_LunFin` time DEFAULT '21:00:00',
  `DE_MarDeb` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `DE_MarFin` time DEFAULT '21:00:00',
  `DE_MerDeb` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `DE_MerFin` time DEFAULT '21:00:00',
  `DE_JeuDeb` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `DE_JeuFin` time DEFAULT '21:00:00',
  `DE_VenDeb` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `DE_VenFin` time DEFAULT '21:00:00',
  `DE_SamDeb` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `DE_SamFin` time DEFAULT '21:00:00',
  `DE_DimDeb` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `DE_DimFin` time DEFAULT '21:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2011 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`CO_Facturation_Adresse`,`CO_Livraison_Adresse` are id retailer, but i want to take back from the retailer the adress and not the id

Comment: yes thats what i want. To explaine when i do my request for an order, instead of having an integer for adress i want to directly have the adress of this retailer.

Comment: there is no relation, i just have the id of the retailer in the order and i have to deal with it

Comment: they are integer but i started to change my values colums so now he puts the id in the varchar and i just need to make a sql request to obtain the adress instead of the retailer id. A student did this DB during his intership

Comment: there is only an interger in CO_Facturation_Adresse,CO_Livraison_Adresse even if they are declared as varchar. And no relation like foreign key or something else declare

Comment: CO_Facturation_Adresse,CO_Livraison_Adresse those 2 are the retailer's ID.

Comment: the matching id is DE_No its the primary key of the table

Comment: i didn't put the entier sql script cause he is 6000/7000 lines only for 1 tables, and i didn't find the alter table in the script

Comment: he can match to both, or be different for both cause the shipping adress can be different of the invoice adress or it can be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`select o.field1, o.field2, r.DE_Adresse from commande AS ord inner join detaillant AS ret ON ord.CO_Facturation_Adresse = ret.DE_No;`

I am not sure which fields you are trying to select, but the basic idea is that you select the fields that you want instead of just everything(*).  Then join on the the two tables where the ID's match.

Comment: i have put the sql code of my tables much easy to understand like this i think ^^

Answer (score 0):

With what you have posted, I think you are trying to use a `subquery` to get all the retailers id. Something like

```
Select * from order where address in (
select distinct ID from retailers
)
```